# Iterator.hasNext() goes nuts after remove() from collection

Tags: java

The code is pretty simple:

```
    List lst1 = new ArrayList(){{add("1");}};
    Iterator it = lst1.iterator();
    System.out.println(it.hasNext());
    it.next();
    System.out.println(it.hasNext());
    lst1.remove(0);
    System.out.println(it.hasNext());
```

I know that you should never remove from a collection while iterating through its iterator, please don't tell me that.

Instead, please give me a sane explanation why would a remove() operation change the value returned by hasNext() from *false* to *true*:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/sun-jdk-1.6/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

true
false
true
```

hasNext() API documentation clearly states that it should return *true* ONLY if there are more elements in the iterator, and calling next() returns an element. The output proves that it's not the case with SUN JDK 1.6

IBM JDK doesn't do that, hasNext returns *false* after remove() gets called:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/ibm-jdk-bin-1.6/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3260sr9fp2-20110625_01(SR9 FP2))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 jvmxi3260sr9-20110624_85526 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

true
false
false
```

Is there a bug in Sun/Oracle hasNext() method? Or, is there a bug in IBM hasNext() method? Or, should I just not bother with all that?

Comment: Since you are violating an invariant, you can't expect any 'sane' behavior.

Comment: a sane explanation? for doing something despite knowing you should not? maybe you should try the methods from `ListIterator`...

Comment: my guess would be a `index>=size` vs `index==size` in the hasNext() test

Comment: @ratchetfreak - correct, here the source code (ArrayList.Itr): `public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size;
        }`

Comment: Why was this question downvoted. It is a very common problem that one would have, and a question that has a reasonable answer.

Comment: Congratulations..you encountered 8 year old bug. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4902078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Iterator.remove():
"The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method."

So it is **unspecified**, meaning that NOTHING is a bug. It could format your harddisk in this case, and still not be incorrect.

Comment: It's a bug that this info is placed in Iterator.remove(), how are they expecting me to read it if I wasn't even using it?

Answer (score 5):

While iterating over a regular Collection, you must use [`Iterator.remove();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) to remove the current element. Any attempt at modification (adding or removing) of the Collection while iterating will throw an [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

However, there are special Collections that allow concurrent modification to the Collection while iterating, such as [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) et al, but element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove, set, and add) are not supported (these methods throw UnsupportedOperationException).

Comment: hm... I'm not getting ConcurrentModificationException in the code listing for some reason

Comment: That exception will occur if you try to call `next()` -- to actually *use* the iterator -- after that `remove()` call.

Comment: but in case of IBM behavior I would not call next() because hasNext() is false

Answer (score 4):

To really answer your question (*why* this happens), you need to look in the `java.util.AbstractList.Itr` inner class, which is returned by the `iterator` method of `AbstractList` (`ArrayList` does not overwrite that method). The implementation of `hasNext` there looks like this:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size();
}
```

Your `remove()` call changed the value returned by `size()` but did not modify the `cursor` value hold by the `Itr` instance, so the two values are now different.

If they would have performed a "less than" check instead of `!=`, the returned value would have been what you expected, but they assumed `!=` can only mean "less than", unless you modify the collection from outside, which is "illegal"; and in this case, any subsequent call to `next()` would result in an exception anyway.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I was looking into the hasNext too, having no idea that the contract that it was supposed to implement was  described in a different method that I didn't use.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is clear:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying
>   collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way
>   other than by calling [the `remove`] method.

The important word here is *unspecified*. This means that once you've modified the underlying collection then the iterator can do *anything*! `hasNext` might return `true`; it might return `false`; it might throw an exception; etc, etc.